# git not working in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, 16.04, git, libraries

Recently I upgraded my laptop to Ubuntu 16.04.

This has apparently caused `git` to stop working.

Specifically, when I call any `git` command, I get the following error:

```
$ git st
git: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Ubuntu 16.04 appears to use `libcrypto.so.10`, not the earlier `libcrypto.so.0.9.8`.  One might suspect that this implies that my version of `git` is out of date, but when I go to upgrade it, I'm told it's already the newest version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install git --upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
```

What is going on here, and what should I do?

Comment: What do `which git` and `git --version` say? Maybe there's an older binary elsewhere on your system?

Comment: @steeldriver can't run `git --version` for the reason mentioned.  `which git` just returns `./git`.

Comment: So... is there an executable called `git`  in your current directory? and `.` is in your `$PATH`? What does `/usr/bin/git --version` and/or `/usr/bin/git status` say?

Comment: @steeldriver sorry, i was calling `which git` from the directory where i'd just cloned the `git` repo.  outside that directory, i get `/usr/local/bin/git`.

Comment: @steeldriver it appears i have another copy of `git` at `/usr/bin/git` that does work.  how should i remove the corrupted version at `/usr/local/bin/git`?

Answer (score 0):

What does `which git` say?  That will tell you which copy of git is being run and if that is not the same one provided by the git package ( `dpkg -L git` ), then you have an older copy in the given location ( probably one you compiled yourself in /usr/local ) that is being used rather than the one from the git package.  Get rid of the one you compiled yourself.

Comment: how would you recommend i get rid of the one i compiled myself?

Comment: @dbliss, if you still have the source you built it from, then it may support `make uninstall`... otherwise you have to manually find the files and delete them.